# XSLT generate table into HTML iframe from XML metadata file

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, iframe

I'm trying to generate table into an HTML iframe from XML metadata file. I'm using an XSLT file I've tried to setup myself which select each metadata type by their tag and their value, wanting it to display in a table inside an HTML iframe.

I've tried customize the XSLT several times aswell as tried to use XSL on the fly inside the script. I've added the proper output method as html aswell and the xmlns gimp (as it is gimp image metadata). At the moment the metadata displays but not in a table, just in continous text within the iframe. HTML, JS and CSS aswell as xml data retrieval seem to be in place. I want the XSL to retrieve the metadata tags and their values and display them in a table under headers 'description' and 'value'. I'm new to XSL and would be really grateful for any pointers or tips as to what might be faulty with the code.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
         <div class="row justify-content-center">

               <button onclick="displayIframe1()">Metadata for the Baltic Tower</button>
               <div id="iframeDisplay"></div>

         </div 
      </div
```

Javascript:

```
function displayIframe1() {
    document.getElementById("iframeDisplay").innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"../collection/metadata_images/metadata_baltictower.xml\" height=\"200\" width=\"300\"></iframe>";
}
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:gimp="http://example.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="gimp">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
        media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet"
                href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
                crossorigin="anonymous" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        </head>
        <html>

            <body>

                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="gimp-metadata/iptc-tag">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="tag-name" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="tag-value" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    
                    <xsl:for-each select="gimp-metadata/xmp-tag">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="tag-name" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="tag-value" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gimp-metadata>
    <iptc-tag>
        <tag-name>Iptc.Application2.DateCreated</tag-name>
        <tag-mode>single</tag-mode>
        <tag-value>2023-05-20</tag-value>
    </iptc-tag>
    <iptc-tag>
        <tag-name>Iptc.Application2.Urgency</tag-name>
        <tag-mode>combo</tag-mode>
        <tag-value>3</tag-value>
    </iptc-tag>
    <iptc-tag>
        <tag-name>Iptc.Application2.SubLocation</tag-name>
        <tag-mode>single</tag-mode>
        <tag-value>Pildammsparken</tag-value>
    </iptc-tag>

<xmp-tag>
        <tag-name>Xmp.dc.description</tag-name>
        <tag-mode>multi</tag-mode>
        <tag-value>An image of the Baltic Tower as part of the entrance for the Baltic Exhibiton in
            Malmo, Sweden, in 1914.
            Book source: Baltiska utstallningen 1914 Brefkortsalbum (1914). Author/publisher
            unknown.</tag-value>
    </xmp-tag>
    <xmp-tag>
        <tag-name>Xmp.dc.subject</tag-name>
        <tag-mode>multi</tag-mode>
        <tag-value>Baltic Tower, Baltic Exhibition, Malmo, 1914.</tag-value>
    </xmp-tag>
    <xmp-tag>
        <tag-name>Xmp.dc.rights</tag-name>
        <tag-mode>single</tag-mode>
        <tag-value>Lag (1960:729) §§7, 44.</tag-value>
    </xmp-tag>
    <xmp-tag>
        <tag-name>Xmp.photoshop.CaptionWriter</tag-name>
        <tag-mode>single</tag-mode>
        <tag-value>Epson Perfection V600 Photo Scanner</tag-value>
    </xmp-tag>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 1vw;
    font-family: 'Palatino', 'Palatino Linotype', 'Palatino LT STD', 'Book Antiqua', 'Georgia,serif';
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
nav,
footer {
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    margin-bottom: 1vw;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1vw;
}

h2 {
    padding: 1vw;
}

h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1vw;

}

h4  {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    padding: 1vw;
}

#details {
    padding: 2vw;
    margin: 1vw;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 1vw;
    margin-top: 1vw;
}

.copyright {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

.copyright_logos,
.copyright_text {
    display: inline;
}

.copyright_logo {
    width: 1vw;
    margin: .15vw;
}





* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.gallery {
    display: none;
}

img {
    margin-top: 21px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:  100px;
    height: 465px;

}

.about {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 75%;
}

/* Container for gallery */
.gallery-container {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 75%;
}

/* Buttons for next & previous */
.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Black background color on hover */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* "Next button" positioned to the right */
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* Number images */
.number {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

/* Indicators */
.indicator {
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}

.active,
.indicator:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading */
.fade1 {
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

/* Decrease text size on smaller screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {

    .prev,
    .next,
    .text {
        font-size: 11px
    }
}


.overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    top: 5;
    color: #000000; 
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: How does the XML you are loading look? Does the XSLT work in a context (e.g. editor, command line) outside of the browser and just fails inside of the browser? Is the XML and XSLT in the browser loaded over HTTP(S)? Loading from the file system is kind of blocked nowadays in all browsers due to security problems.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thank you for your reply. I've added the XML code. The files are loaded from the file system. What's the difference in loading over HTTP(S)? I'm new to programming so only checked my code through different browsers or live server so far.

Comment: I don't see the XML sample referencing any stylesheet with e.g. `<?xml-stylesheet href="sheet.xsl"?>`. That is what you would need to do if you expect the browser to apply an XSLT stylesheet to an XML document you load into a window or frame. However, as I already said, for file system based approaches, browsers do no longer even support that for security problems they run into and thought to be best "fixed" by not permitting an XML loaded from the file system to reference/load an XSLT stylesheet from the file system.

Comment: I understand. Is there any other way to load the XML data into the website iframe?

Comment: XSLT can be applied with the XSLTProcessor API through JavaScript but fetching resources like an XML or XSLT with JavaScript is often as restricted on the file system as the `xml-stylesheet href` access. So unless your aim is to host your stuff on a HTTP server none of that makes sense in the context of a browser.